# RF interference for ultra low power wireless device

Tags: wireless

Is it routine and/or has anyone performed tests on active interference when developing ultra low power wireless devices?

You area going to test range of your device and tune your antenna/matching network and all that. And you have to pass FCC testing, but what about active interference, particularly in the 2.4 ghz bands. Things like baby monitors, micro waves, or other nearby wireless devices.

I am particularly thinking about situations where you have sensors or other devices where you are trying to minimize the amount of time the devices is on. Maybe an energy harvesting wireless switch/button for example. Optimally your device just turns on, blasts out it's little bit of data and is back to sleep. You don't want a switch that only works if the microwave isn't on, etc.

If so is there a standard test protocol for this?